# Play in/with video player software

Tags: grammaticality

When I play a video or audio file using a media player like VLC, should I say *play in VLC* or *play with VLC*?

Which one is correct?

Comment: Both are acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think either would be acceptable, because we use multiple metaphors when thinking about computer programs.

I think "with" is more common, because a computer program is most often imagined as a device that you use to achieve some purpose. Similarly, it would be more common to say that you write a term paper *with* Microsoft Word

But we also think of a computer program as a virtual space in which we perform activities (clicking on things, dragging things, typing, etc.). In this model, we can say that we play a video file *in* VLC, or edit the term paper *in* MS Word.